# (Elasticsearch) Convert Unix formatted data into timestamp (without changing the mappings)

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

We're executing an Elasticsearch query like this using PHP API:

```
$params = [
        //please ignore the variables below, 
        //we made it in dynamic parameter-based in our function, 
        //that's why they're variables
        'index' => $ourIndex,
        'type'  => $ourType,
        'from'  => $from,
        'size'  => $page_size,
        'body'  => [
            "query" => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            "query_string" => [
                                "default_field" => $content,
                                "query" => "$keywords"
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "range" => [
                                "@timestamp" => [
                                    "from" => $parseParams['pub_date_start'],
                                    "to"   => $parseParams['pub_date_end'],
                                    'format' => "yy-MMM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

The query above works with our `@timestamp` field because its type is on `date`

```
"@timestamp" : {
      "type" : "date"
}
```

And a sample value is like this:

```
"@timestamp" : "2019-06-17T16:53:55.778Z"
```

However, we want to target our `pub_date` field in our index, and in its mapping, the field has a type of `long`

```
"pub_date" : {
    "type" : "long"
},
```

so it has this kind of values when we're displaying the documents:

```
"pub_date" : 1510358400
```

When we changed the query above to target instead of `@timestamp` to `pub_date`, it now displays an error like this:

[image: Error]
**Tried Solutions** 
I tried to add an additional format `epoch_millis` in the `format` property:

```
[
    "range" => [
        "pub_date" => [
            "from" => $parseParams['pub_date_start'],
            "to"   => $parseParams['pub_date_end'],
            'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd||yy-MMM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'||epoch_millis",
        ]
    ]
]
```

But still fails

**Main Question** 
I feel that the Unix formatted values cant be recognized by the `range` query of Elasticsearch so that's why the query fails. Is there a work-around for this without changing the **MAPPINGS** of the index?

Because the other possible solutions suggested to change the mapping, but we already have around 25 million documents in the index, so we thought formatting it in PHP would be a nicer approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the field is of type `long` and stores the unix timestamp, simply convert the date in `$parseParams['pub_date_start']` and `$parseParams['pub_date_end']` to unix timestamp using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Update the range query as below:

```
"range" => [
  "pub_date" => [
      "from" => strtotime($parseParams['pub_date_start']),
      "to"   => strtotime($parseParams['pub_date_end']),
    ]
]
```

Comment: thank you very much sir @NishantSaini, this works like a charm!

Comment: Glad it helped :)